# Binding classes with property injection to kernel in inversify

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, inversifyjs

I am trying to achieve dependency injection on my node project via [inversify](http://inversify.io/).

I have a kernel config like this: `inversify.config.ts`

```
import "reflect-metadata";
import {Kernel, interfaces} from "inversify";

import {Config} from "./config";
import {Collection} from "./collection";

let kernel = new Kernel();

kernel.bind<Config>("Config").to(Config).inSingletonScope();
// kernel.bind<interfaces.Newable<Collection>>("Collection").toConstructor<Collection>(Collection);
// it works without the line above
```

A class: `config.ts`

```
import {injectable} from "inversify";
@injectable()
export class Config {
  constructor() {}
}
```

A class with property DI `collection.ts`

```
import {injectable} from "inversify";
import getDecorators from "inversify-inject-decorators";
import kernel from "../inversify.config";
let {lazyInject} = getDecorators(kernel);

@injectable()
export class Collection {
  @lazyInject(Config)
  private Config: Config;

  constructor(a: string, b: string) {}
}
```

Everything works as expected if I don't bind a class with property injection. When I try to bind a class with `@lazyInject` as shown in the example

```
kernel.bind<interfaces.Newable<Collection>>("Collection").toConstructor<Collection>(Collection);
```

import line in `inversify.config.ts` starts processing  `Collection.ts` and the line

```
import kernel from "../inversify.config";`
```

in it. However as we arrived `Collection.ts` while we already processing `inversify.config.ts` file line

```
import kernel from "../inversify.config";`
```

somehow returns `undefined` making kernel `undefined` for `Collection` class. Therefore `@lazyInject` DI fails.

Eventually when I try to read `Config` in `Collection` it fails with:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at resolve (node_modules/inversify-inject-decorators/lib/decorators.js:24:30)
    at Category.getter (node_modules/inversify-inject-decorators/lib/decorators.js:6:47)
```

I wonder if there is a way to accomplish binding a class with property DI via `@lazyInject` **without** moving kernel definition into the same file with one of the classes. I am looking for a way to **import** kernel as it is now, but make it work properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that you have a circular dependency:

[image]

I'm going to change your code and add a couple of additional files. Nothe that the he file `types.ts` is not needed but it is recommended to keep all your type identifiers in one single location.

After changing your code the dependency diagram will change to the following:

[image]

As you can se we have eliminated the circular dependency.

#### inversify.config.ts

```
import "reflect-metadata";
import {Kernel, interfaces} from "inversify";
import getDecorators from "inversify-inject-decorators";
import { makeProvideDecorator } from "inversify-binding-decorators";

let kernel = new Kernel();
let {lazyInject} = getDecorators(kernel);
let provide = makeProvideDecorator(kernel);

export { lazyInject, provide };
```

#### types.ts

```
let TYPES = {
  Config: "Config",
  Collection: "Collection",
};

export default TYPES;
```

#### config.ts

```
import { provide } from "../inversify.config";
import TYPES from "./types";

@provide(TYPES.Config)
export class Config {
  constructor() {}
}

export default Config;
```

#### collection.ts

```
import { lazyInject, provide } from "../inversify.config";

@provide(TYPES.Collection)
export class Collection {
  @lazyInject(TYPES.Config)
  private Config: Config;
  constructor(a: string, b: string) {}
}

export default Collection;
```

#### main.ts

You need to import all your dependencies when they are imported @provide is executed and then bindings are generated.

```
import Config from "./lib/config";
import Collection from "./models/collection";

//...
```

We have been able to eliminate the circular dependency using the `@provide` decorator from [inversify-binding-decorators](https://github.com/inversify/inversify-binding-decorators).

Comment: I had issues when not doing a "export default" for my identifiers as then the TYPES will be undefined. I don't get why it only works with a 'default' export? Does this have something to do with metadata generation?